# Grand Totals are showing twice with two times to their original value Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, grand-total

When I extends **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract** in my custom module it is showing grand total twice with two times to their original value. Here's screenshot.

[image]

Here's what I do in my module

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Ranosys_SpecialPrice>
        <version>0.1.3</version>
    </Ranosys_SpecialPrice>
</modules>
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <specialprice>
                    <class>Ranosys_SpecialPrice_Model_Total_Address_Grand</class>
                 </specialprice>
            </totals>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
</config>
```

**Grand.php**

```
<?php

class Ranosys_SpecialPrice_Model_Total_Address_Grand extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract {


public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {

    parent::collect($address);
    $grandTotal = $address->getGrandTotal();
    $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();
    $paymentMethod = $address->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();

    $store = $address->getQuote()->getStore();
    $totals = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());
    $totals = $store->roundPrice($totals);
    $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());
    $baseTotals = $store->roundPrice($baseTotals);


    if ($paymentMethod == 'cashondelivery') {
        $address->setGrandTotal(round(($grandTotal + $totals), 0));
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal(round(($baseGrandTotal + $baseTotals), 0));
    } else {
        $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal + $totals);
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal + $baseTotals);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add grand total information to address
 *
 * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
 * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand
 */
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $address->addTotal(array(
        'code'  => $this->getCode(),
        'title' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Grand Total'),
        'value' => $address->getGrandTotal(),
        'area'  => 'footer',
    ));
    return $this;
}

}
```

I Copied code of Grand.php from **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand** file and do some modifications as per my requirement. please help what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update below code:

```
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $address->addTotals(array(
        'code'  => $this->getCode(),
        'title' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Grand Total'),
        'value' => $address->getGrandTotal(),
        'area'  => 'footer',
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

To

```
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $address->collectTotals(array(
        'code'  => $this->getCode(),
        'title' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Grand Total'),
        'value' => $address->getGrandTotal(),
        'area'  => 'footer',
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ram . Now it is showing one grandtotal but grand total is double from original one.

Comment: I think core file is also calling that's why value got doubled. Am I right @Ram

Comment: Yes, absolutly :)

Comment: What should I need to do @Ram Please help